# OpenTK C# Windows Phone (8)

Tags: c#, opengl, windows-phone-8, direct3d, opentk

I am trying to port a desktop C# project to Windows Phone (8) but my problem is that it uses OpenTK in some parts to show some 3d models. After some research I have determined that OpenTK is a .NET or mono binding to OpenGL. I do know though that Windows Phone does not support OpenGL, only XNA and Direct3D.

My question now is, what can I do to make this code work. Is there already a port of some sort of OpenTK to Windows Phone; some port of OpenTK to direct3d that can that I can then port to WP, but I am not sure if I will be able access Direct3D from C# though; will I have to somehow figure out how to transalte the OpenTK code to XNA code (is that even (practically) possible); or is there some other hopefully simpler way of doing.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that there is no simple way of automatically translating your OpenTK code to DirectX.

I would port the code to http://www.monogame.net/ which uses OpenTK under the hood for Windows,Android,iOS and Linux and SharpDX for Windows Phone8 and Windows 8 Store/Metro.

That way your code becomes independent from the target platform, but there is some work involved in getting your OpenTK to move to monogame.
So that's probably not what you wanted to hear, sorry.

Comment: I also thought of that, but that's rather sensless because the application I am trying to port already supports all other platforms. It would be the same amount of porting effort.

Comment: Except if OpenTK -> MonoGame is simpler than OpenTK -> SharpDX, is it?

Comment: Well the sense would be that you end up with one code base that works for all platforms (monoGame) versus having to maintain two afterwards (OpenTK & SharpDX). I'm not short which one is easier, probably depends on your DirectX skills. For me personally the monoGame route would probably be easier since I have more experience with XNA than DirectX directly.